# Create distance matrix from the result of pdist

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to create a matrix from the result of pdist.
pdist returns a vector of distances: 1-2, 1-3, 1-4.. 2-3.. etc.

i have tried to use this as suggested to get the upper triangle:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b=triu(ones(5),1);
b(b==1)=a;
```

but this returns

```
0     1     2     4     7 
0     0     3     5     8
0     0     0     6     9
0     0     0     0    10
0     0     0     0     0
```

Is there a oneliner/function to do this correctly?

Comment: What result do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand from the title you want to create a square matrix from PDIST function result. It can be easily done with [SQUAREFORM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html) function. And it works in both directions.

```
a = pdist(...);
asq = squareform(a);
```

Comment: Well, it was almost a mind-reading. :) May be you should work on a question formulation to make it useful for others.